# Eclipse Bukkit failed to export my jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I was just programming a whole day on a Bukkit plugin and now it wont export?
Here is the error message

```
JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
Exported with compile warnings: WorkingWG/src/com/rof/staff/WorldGuard.java
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/WorkingWG/plugin.yml
```

Here is an image of my packages etc.

[Look left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD4CO.png)

This is what is in my plugin.yml:

```
main: com.rof.staff.WorldGuard
name: WorldGuard
author: RoflFrankoc
version: 1.0
commands:
  wg:
    description: The main command!
    usage: /<command> <argument>
permissions:
  wg.all:
    description: The main command permission!
    default: op
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the Eclipse project, right click and select "refresh".

Eclipse maintains a timestamp for project files. If you modify a file from outside of Eclipse, it requires a manual refresh.